# Interest rate calculation produces numbers that are too large

Tags: java, math

I am having some issues with my math in coding this program. I am making a program that will take the users input for investment, year, and interest, and output it as a table. It all seems to be working properly - except the output is not adding correctly, and is not calculating the interest.  Here is my code:

```
      double investmentAmount; //the amount the user chooses to invest, expressed as a double
investmentAmount = Double.parseDouble(InputInvestmentAmount);
double Interest; // amount of interest in percent, expressed as a double
Interest = Double.parseDouble(InputInterest);
double YearsInvested; //the total years (under 15) the user wants to invest, expressed as adouble
YearsInvested = Double.parseDouble(InputYearsInvested);
double Year = 0; //a starting point for the year
double Total;
  do {
     Year++; //the year

     Interest = (investmentamount * (Interest / 100));
     Total = investmentamount + Interest;
     System.out.format("%5.0f%32.2f%28.2f%25.2f%n", Year, investmentamount, Interest, Total);
     investmentAmount = Total + investmentamount;

  } while (YearsInvested <= 15 && Year <= YearsInvested - 1);
```

For instance, if I input $50, at 1% interest, for 15 years, I get infinity as an answer.

```
Years Invested      Amount in Account                     Interest                  Total
    1                           50.00                        0.50                    50.50
    2                          100.50                        0.50                   101.00
    3                          201.50                        1.01                   202.52
    4                          404.02                        4.09                   408.11
    5                          812.13                       33.22                   845.35
    6                         1657.48                      550.66                  2208.14
    7                         3865.61                    21286.57                 25152.19
    8                        29017.80                  6176894.63               6205912.43
    9                      6234930.23             385125070004.00          385131304934.23
   10                 385137539864.45   1483261220014673600000.001483261220399811100000.00
   11       1483261220784948600000.0022000638479419373000000000000000000000000.0022000638479419373000000000000000000000000.00
   1222000638479419373000000000000000000000000.004840280935021083600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.004840280935021083600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00
   134840280935021083600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00234283195299285770000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00234283195299285770000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00
   14234283195299285770000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00                    Infinity                 Infinity
```

I apologize for the messiness of the output.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your code example, for example what data types you have declared for your variables. I suspect you are using a float or double, and have exceeded the maximum size.

Comment: Please accept my edit

Comment: Do the calculations by hand.  Do they look right?

Comment: Edited. I am doing the calculations right now.**EDIT** I see the problem is with my declaration of the value of the  "investmentAmount" variable.

Comment: This line `investmentAmount = Total + investmentamount;` is wrong. Try this instead: `investmentAmount = Total;` Your calculations are mistakenly adding the investment amount twice, which is why you get such large values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to also make sure that the program adds the original investment amount each year. So, for instance, the user inputs $100.00 the first year, the interest gives them $102.00 at the end of the year, and they input another $100 at the start of the second year. I apologize that that was unclear.

Comment: @WhyCodingWhy did the answer by Payam solve your question?

Comment: @WhyCodingWhy if my solution has resolved your issue kindly close this question by picking my solution as the answer of this question. If it's not the answer of your question than you might comment it out. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing the variables and overwriting it.

```
   double investmentAmount; //the amount the user chooses to invest, expressed as a double
   investmentAmount = Double.parseDouble(InputInvestmentAmount);
   Double OrginalInvestment; 
   OrginalInvestment=investmentAmount;//this is too keep your orginal investment
   double Interest; // amount of interest in percent, expressed as a double
   Interest = Double.parseDouble(InputInterest);
   double YearsInvested; //the total years (under 15) the user wants to invest, expressed as a double
   YearsInvested = Double.parseDouble(InputYearsInvested);
   double Zero = 0; //a starting point for the year
   double Total;
    System.out.println("Years Invested \t\tAmount in Account\t\tInterest\t\tTotal");
   if (YearsInvested >=16)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I am sorry. Please make sure that you are investing your money for "
               + "less than 16 years.", "Compound Investing Calculator",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
   double IntrestMoney;
   do {
       Zero++; //the year

        IntrestMoney = investmentAmount*(Interest/100);
        Total = investmentAmount+IntrestMoney;

       System.out.format("%5.2f%32f%28f%25f%n",Zero,investmentAmount,IntrestMoney,Total);
       investmentAmount=Total+OrginalInvestment; //
   }
   while (YearsInvested <= 15 && Zero<=YearsInvested-1); 

 }
```

**This is the output if you use $200 as your investment, 10% as your rate, 5 years as your duration :**

```
Years Invested      Amount in Account       Interest        Total
 1.00                      200.000000                   20.000000               220.000000
 2.00                      420.000000                   42.000000               462.000000
 3.00                      662.000000                   66.200000               728.200000
 4.00                      928.200000                   92.820000              1021.020000
 5.00                     1221.020000                  122.102000              1343.122000
```

**Edit**

since too long decimal points are going to mess up your table I suggest to round your answers to 4 decimal values you can use this following method:

```
  public static double round(double value, int places) {
  if (places < 0) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
  bd = bd.setScale(places, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  return bd.doubleValue();
 }
```

Keep in mind you have to call the `round()` method to change your `Total` value:

```
Total = round((investmentAmount+IntrestMoney),4);
```

Comment: Very neat and organized, everything is clear and easy to see, it's rare for someone as low reputation as you. +1

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper Thanks for your update. I have changed the source codes it's working now. I might be new here but I'm a massive stackoverflow user/fan :p .. I finally decided to contribute back to this awesome community :)

Comment: Glad to hear it mate, keep it up!